# If Null then Clear if not then leave alone

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form I have a search function setup to where I can type in any of the fields and search for that particular data, the course fields though need to be CLEARED if I have not preselected something for their fields. I have their default values at null. Currently the code looks like

```
Private Function SearchClear()
Me.cboDevelopment1 = ""
Me.cboDevelopment2 = ""
Me.cboDevelopment3 = ""
Me.cboDevelopment4 = ""
Me.cboDevelopment5 = ""
'focus on ID text box
Me.txtEmpID.SetFocus
'set button edit to enable
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
'change caption of button add to Add
Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add Record"
'clear tag on txt id for reset new
Me.txtEmpID.Tag = ""
End Function
```

I would like to write in saying IF NULL then to clear the fields, but if not then let them be so the designated courses can be looked up.

I even tried adding in And Is Not Null to the search query that is run in the background but that did not work.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Is the question how to test for null?

Comment: Yes, the values are automatically null. SO when I run the search if the value is still null I need the null to clear, but if the value is anything other than null I need it to be left alone

Comment: When you say you 'need the null to clear' do you mean you want to replace any null values with empty strings?

Comment: Yes so the cell will be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a form for searching for courses.

You say you have set the defaults to null so would it look like this?

```
Me.cboDevelopment1 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment2 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment3 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment4 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment5 = NULL
```

Or, when you say they have to be cleared if they don't have something preselected the users has selected a value and now your form looks like this before you run your search?

```
Me.cboDevelopment1 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment2 = VALUE1
Me.cboDevelopment3 = NULL
Me.cboDevelopment4 = VALUE2
Me.cboDevelopment5 = NULL
```

And then the user would click search and you would perform this CLEAR you are looking for before searching?

Comment: It needs to clear the fields if the value is null BEFORE the search is run

Comment: @user2119980 Perhaps I am misunderstanding but if the value is Null before you run your search then the field is already clear.  Could you post your full search code so that we can see the results of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The full search code is massive, I have the default value of the combo box set to Display Null

Comment: @user2119980 I have updated my answer.  Are my assumptions correct?